# PL/SQL: How select data from table and input into package accepting array type?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL email package that looks like:

```
create or replace package mail_pkg 
as
PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE; -- this avoids ORA-04068 error
type array is table of varchar2(255);

procedure send( p_sender_email in varchar2,
            p_from         in varchar2 default null,
            p_to           in array default array(),
            p_cc           in array default array(),
            p_bcc          in array default array(),
            p_subject      in varchar2 default null,
            p_body         in clob default null);
```

Example usage would be:

```
 begin
    mail_pkg.send( p_sender_email => 'tim@company1.com',
               p_from => 'John Smith <johns@company2.com>',
               p_to => mail_pkg.array( 'greg@company3.com','sarah@company4.com'),
               p_cc => mail_pkg.array( 'admin@company5.com' ), 
               p_bcc => mail_pkg.array( 'sue@company5.com' ), 
               p_subject => 'This is my subject', 
               p_body => 'Hello, this is the mail you requested.' );
    end;
```

[note: for anyone looking for an e-mail package, here's the link I got it from:
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:255615160805 ]

I want to use it to send an email, but the email addresses in the `p_to` input must be input dynamically. That is, I can't hardcode them like above. They need to come from a SELECT statement. I'm familiar with writing select statements, but I don't know how to to get the result of the selecte statement into a format that I can include in the

```
p_to => mail_pkg.array( WHAT GOES HERE??? ),
```

code.

Anyone know how I can connect a SELECT statement (which returns some email addresses) to work with this package?

UPDATE:

Based on feedback below, the solution is:

```
create or replace procedure send_email ( 
  in_name IN varchar2
 )

AS

v_body clob;  
v_to_array mail_pkg.array := mail_pkg.array();
v_counter int := 1;

BEGIN

FOR r IN (SELECT person_email FROM email_table WHERE company_name=in_name) LOOP
  v_to_array.extend;
  v_to_array(v_counter) := r.person_email;
  v_counter := v_counter +1;
END LOOP;

-- send email

mail_pkg.send( p_sender_email => 'sam@company2.com',
               p_from => 'admin@company2.com',
               p_to => v_to_array,
               p_bcc => mail_pkg.array( 'tim@company3.com' ), 
               p_subject => 'the subject line goes here', 
               p_body => 'This is the body message.' );  

END send_email;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it in two steps. The first step is to use a `SELECT` statement in a loop and populate an array; the second step is to use that array in your call to `mail_pkg.send`, maybe something like this:

```
declare
  v_counter number := 1;
  v_to_arr mail_pkg.array := mail_pkg.array();
begin
  for r in Select email_address from table_of_email_addresses loop
    v_to_arr.extend;
    v_to_arr(v_counter) := r.email_address;
    v_counter := v_counter +1;
  end loop;

  mail_pkg.send(p_to => v_to_arr, ... );
  --note: this code may require some fine-tuning.
  ...
end ;
```

---

As suggested in the comments, a bulk collect could probably be used here, might be as simple as:

```
declare
  v_to_arr mail_pkg.array := mail_pkg.array();
begin

  Select email_address
  bulk collect into v_to_arr
  from table_of_email_addresses;

  mail_pkg.send(p_to => v_to_arr, ... );
  --note: this code may require some fine-tuning.
  ...
end ;
```

I'm a little rusty on bulk operations, you might want to read up on them yourself.

Comment: Thanks so much FrustratedWithFormsDes, I'm getting a compile error: `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SEND'`. Any idea what it could be? (I'll update my original posting above to show what my current code looks like...)

Comment: @ggkmath: That might be because I didn't complete the function call - too lazy to copy/paste *all* of your parameters. :P

Comment: @ggkmath: Ok, I also updated to make sure that the `v_to_arr` was of type `mail_pkg.array`. If there is a globally defined type `array` that might not be compatible with `mail_pkg.array`.

Comment: That was it! Compiles fine now. Thanks so much!!!!! I've updated the UPDATE section to show the final code.

Comment: Why not just `SELECT ... BULK COLLECT INTO ` ?