# Insert part of a PL/SQL output into a message body and email it

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am trying create a PL/SQL program that will allow me to automatically send out emails from the data picked up in the output of the SQL command.

My current output columns are

```
DB_NAME    SC_NAME    RO_NAME    User_NAME    EMAIL_ID.
```

There are about 293 rows in the output. Out of those 293... there are about 11 distinct outputs in the the `User_NAME` column.
Now for example: One of the distinct outputs in the `User_NAME` column is John. Now... for every row that is John... I want to send an email to the email id mentioned in the corresponding `EMAIL_ID` row.

How do I extract that information to send an email based on each of the distinct outputs?

****EDIT****

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Zzm.png

If you look at the image above... I want to email to JMGR@gmail.com the first three rows ( where User_name is JOHN). And then i want to email MMGR@gmail.com the 4th row (where User_name is MIKE)
And so forth.

The image above is all i have so far.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Please see my edit and that might make more sense. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: `select distinct DB_NAME    SC_NAME    RO_NAME    User_NAME    EMAIL_ID from your_table` will fetch all unique rows. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No there is not what i am looking for.
I am trying to automate an email that runs every week that sends the corresponding managers the list of their employees (employees = User_name).
I am assuming i would have to use some sort of a loop function?

Comment: No that is not what i am looking for. I am trying to automate an email that runs every week that sends the corresponding managers the list of their employees (employees = User_name). I am assuming i would have to use some sort of a loop function?

Comment: @user2676690 Yes you need a loop, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444130/pl-sql-how-select-data-from-table-and-input-into-package-accepting-array-type

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the LISTAGG() function:

```
select EMAIL_ID,
       LISTAGG(DB_NAME || ' ' || SC_NAME || ' ' || RO_NAME, ', ') WITHIN group(order by DB_NAME, SC_NAME, RO_NAME) MESSAGE
 from table
 group by EMAIL_ID
```

Comment: Obviously you can change the query to suit your needs, but LISTAGG is the key.